# RuntimeError: expected device cpu and dtype Float but got device cpu and dtype Bool

Tags: pytorch, allennlp

I use [this](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/modules/conditional_random_field.py) python script from AllenAI to integrate CRF module (Conditional random fields) layer in my ML-system ...

and execute the following example to test the CRF module.

```py
import torch
from allennlp.modules import ConditionalRandomField

num_tags = 2

model = ConditionalRandomField(num_tags)
    
seq_length = 3  # maximum sequence length in a batch
batch_size = 2  # number of samples in the batch
emissions = torch.randn(seq_length, batch_size, num_tags)
tags = torch.tensor([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=torch.long)  # (seq_length, batch_size)
model(emissions, tags)
```

Upon execution, I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-415939853a93> in <module>
  7 emissions = torch.randn(seq_length, batch_size, num_tags)
  8 tags = torch.tensor([[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=torch.long)  # 
(seq_length, batch_size)
----> 9 model(emissions, tags)

~/anaconda3/envs/torch/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in 
__call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
545                     result = (result,)
546                 input = result
--> 547         if torch._C._get_tracing_state():
548             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
549         else:

<ipython-input-2-2d984bd97cf1> in forward(self, inputs, tags, mask)
329             mask = mask.to(torch.bool)
330 
--> 331         log_denominator = self._input_likelihood(inputs, mask)
332         log_numerator = self._joint_likelihood(inputs, tags, mask)
333 

<ipython-input-2-2d984bd97cf1> in _input_likelihood(self, logits, mask)
249             # In valid positions (mask == True) we want to take the logsumexp over the 
current_tag dimension
250             # of `inner`. Otherwise (mask == False) we want to retain the previous 
alpha.
--> 251             alpha = util.logsumexp(inner, 1) * mask[i].view(batch_size, 1) + alpha * 
(
252                 ~mask[i]
253             ).view(batch_size, 1)

RuntimeError: expected device cpu and dtype Float but got device cpu and dtype Bool
```

I do understand that this is a problem of PyTorch version incompatibility with the functions used in allennlp package, but I am not sure what versions of torch and torchvision it expects.
These are the versions of PyTorch installations on my machine.

```
torch                            1.5.1               
torchvision                      0.4.2
allennlp                         1.0.0
```

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Around Pytorch 1.1 and 1.2 they introduced bool tensors; before that, it was standard to use uint8 tensors for masking. I would try pytorch 1.0 and 1.1. https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.2.0

Comment: Although allennlp seems to be for pytorch 1.6 https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/setup.py#L53 So that might be it. Is there anything preventing you from installing different torch versions and trying them? If it doesn't work for pytorch 1.6, you could open an issue on allennlp's github. (torchvision version shouldn't matter)

Comment: I just tried this example with the latest AllenNLP master, and it works just fine. I have torch 1.6 installed.